# Access from GSuite Spreadsheets formula to Firebase SDK ID token

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-docs, google-workspace

It is not clean for me how firebase authentication should be implemented inside a GSuite formula.

Let's assume I develop a GSuite formula that should work with a third party backend requesting data and displaying the data in Google Spreadsheets. The third party backend requires Firebase ID token as part of the [Bearer authentication](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/) process.

I know how to get the ID token using the Firebase Authentication SDK in an HTML popup window or sidebar. I know that the ID token expired every hour or so and [its auto-refreshed by Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). The problem is that when formula executes it could not have access to the Firebase SDK (am I wrong ?) and therefore it could use expired token that was stored somewhere in user cache. Moreover, if a spreadsheet is open and tries to refresh the data, despite the fact the user is still logged into the Firebase, the formula could not do the call

```js
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

What is the "canonical" way to solve this problem?

TL;DR As it was suggested by Jean-Remi in accepted answer the way to go when there is no way to use the provided libraries is to use the Firebase REST API directly. There are [Firebase Auth REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/) and [Firebase DB Access REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect to use the normal "popup flow" to authenticate in a Google Apps Script (because I suppose that's what means "GSuite formula"), because its execution is server side.

You can either use a service account token to authenticate to your DB, or generate an ID token using the user email retrieved by AppsScript (if that work in your formula).

Take a look at our connector to use Firebase in AppsSript:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@scriptaddicts/gas-firebase-app

Comment: Our intention is to use popup once to let user enter the credentials. Then we hope to  find a way (and that's what the question about) to refresh the token during the formula execution on server side as it is possible for backend. I can't believe the Google hasn't integrated Firebase with GSuite. I asked the question in hope I miss special some way Firebase & GSuite integrated.

Comment: I'm worried about using the Firebase service account in Addin code because it allows to have access to any item in DB. For the Addin would be sufficient to get token and provide token to backend. The backend would have access only to user specific entry of the Firebase DB - that is all the code needs to proceed, the service is a potentially unsecure overkill in this case.

Comment: You don't necessarily provide access to the whole DB. Using customToken generation you can use the user access right to get the data.

Comment: To use a popup, your only choice is currently to display a sidebar or a dialog to the user, starting the user integration from an Action Menu.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Remi for your suggestions! We ended up using the Firebase REST API in AppScript https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/ the same API that you pointed out in your connector. The API provides all necessary functionality for Auth and our app doesn't depend on JS Firebase library. In App script the user logs via the REST API in using email/pwd approach and refresh token is stored along with the ID token (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password ). When the ID token is expired (we store it in cache) is is refreshed via REST.

Comment: Great ! Please keep in mind that spreadsheet editor can edit the attached scripts and check some script properties. So take care to store refresh tokens in the user's properties (if using the property services).

Comment: Firebase being integrated to Apps Script would be so great ! (No more using the UrlFetch quota !)